# Spring Data Rest and Spring MVC hateoas

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I have an angular app, requesting data from a Spring Boot backend with Spring Data Rest. Requests to repositories generate responses with HATEOAS structure. But when I ask from Spring MVC controller, the response is indifferent structure(natural).

Is there any example where I can achieve the same structure on a particular controller request? I believe I should implement HATEOAS, but haven't seen a single example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find official example [here](https://spring.io/projects/spring-hateoas#samples).

The return value of your controller method should be wrapped in `EntityModel` or `CollectionModel`, so the JSON should be in HAL format.

```java
  @PostMapping("/orders")
  ResponseEntity<EntityModel<Order>> newOrder(@RequestBody Order order) {

    order.setStatus(Status.IN_PROGRESS);
    Order newOrder = orderRepository.save(order);

    return ResponseEntity //
        .created(linkTo(methodOn(OrderController.class).one(newOrder.getId())).toUri()) //
        .body(assembler.toModel(newOrder));
  }
```